# Using jQuery to add/remove attributes if another attribute is added/removed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of textbox elements which the `readonly` attribute gets added to and removed from based on a bunch of different conditions.

Users have complained that pressing the Tab key gets them 'stuck' on a textbox that is readonly.

I want to now add `tabindex='-1'` whenever I set `readonly='readonly'`, and then remove the `tabindex` attribute whenever I remove the `readonly` attribute.

Is there a global event that I can use to do this? I'm trying to avoid finding every instance where it occurs and doing it manually.

Comment: Events are not fired when attributes are added or removed. You should manually call a function to add tabindex when you set readonly..

Comment: I wondered. I should have said function instead of event. But you get what I meant :)

Comment: why don't you change that attr at the same time are changing the readonly?

Comment: $('input').attr('readonly').each(function(e){$(e).attr('tabindex','-1')});

Comment: @DaniP, that's what I was doing. It occurs about 50 times. I could have finished by now instead of taking time to ask this question but I was just curious if there was some elegant solution.

Comment: if an event can be so repetitive on different conditions, next time it's better if your write a function to execute instead write the event each time., without code how can we know that occurs about 50 times . theres is no way to improve your code if you don't include it here

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying `tabindex` each time you set/unset `readonly` on an element, you might use a different strategy:

- Bind all involved elements to a `focus` handler
- Then, if the element is `readonly`, merely trigger a `tab` strike

Something like this (to refine depending on your context):

```
$('.involved-element').focus(function() {
  if (!$(':enabled', this)) {
    $(document).trigger({type:'keydown', which:9});
  }
}
```